# Looking for robust but simple JavaScript framework

Tags: javascript, frameworks, backbone.js

I'm starting a new project that will be heavy on javascript and am looking for a robust framework to prevent me from falling into chaotic structures again.

I've looked into JavascriptMVC but it seems to have a steep learning curve, which is fine but I don't have the time for it on my current project. I need to get started practically right away.

I've played around with Backbone.js, which looks perfect.. only it pretty much just provides me the tools and does not help me much in terms of structure. I still need to manage loading JS files myself either with a third party library or by manually loading them when the page loads. Also it does not enforce any type of directory structure.

Basically I need a javascript framework which provides me with a MVC model (preferably), enforces a certain file structure and doesn't take days to learn the basics of.

I'd appreciate any recommendations. Also if there are perhaps libraries that add this type of functionality on top of Backbone.js that would be an ideal solution.. but I haven't been able to find it myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a dependency manager that also provides routing, model management and enforces a folder structure.  Most of these *will* take some time to learn (that's just the nature of the beast).  The fastest that I can think of would be to use [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) (or [Spine.js](http://maccman.github.com/spine/)) coupled with [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for the dependency management.  The layout of your application will not be *enforced* by your framework, but (on the bright side) you can enforce the layout in a way that follows the MVC pattern **and** makes the most sense to you.

Alternately, if you wanted a full-stack, includes everything you need setup, you could use [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) or [Sencha / ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) - but if you are used to jQuery, it will be quite a bit of a change-up for you.

Answer (score 2):

*"I need something that does both"*

You'll likely need two tools to do the job.

Google Closure's [depswriter](http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/depswriter.html) and [closurebuilder](http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder.html) will provide dependency resolution, compilation and checking, and advanced compression if you need it. The learning curve is small and the structure and compression they provide pay big dividends. They are agnostic of your MVC choice.

For the MVC, both Backbone and Sproutcore 2.0 are outstanding. If FE performance is a major issue, you'll likely need to lean towards the Sproutcore set of tools.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression Sproutcore is really a framework that lets you work with their UI though? I'd still like the flexibility of managing my views and their css manually, is that a possibility with Sproutcore?

Comment: Check out Sproutcore 2.0 - http://blog.sproutcore.com/announcing-sproutcore-2-0/ : "Remember: SproutCore 1.6 is still the best way to write desktop-style apps, and will continue to be maintained and developed by the core team and contributors. Right now, SproutCore 2.0 is the best choice only if you are building web-style apps, or want to augment an existing application."

Answer (score 1):

Outside of Backbone and Javascript MVC, you might want to check out [KnockoutJS](http://www.knockoutjs.com), which is a javascript MVVM framework.

Comment: Thanks, I did check them out.. but from what I can see they take the same approach as Backbone.. which is they provide you the tools but not the structure. I need something that does both. I don't want to have to still create libraries for loading external models, controllers, etc.